# mount a directory into ram but with persistence

Tags: mount, ram

For one of my requirements, I could mount a ramfs parition in /media/user/ramdir and use. (Reduce latency of files read/written by my c program). Not using tmpfs also as that could induce some latency.

I copied my input files supposed to be read by my c program from disk to the mounted ram file system.

```
    mount -t ramfs -o size=100m ramfs /media/user/ramdir
```

If I make any changes or create a new file in the mounted ramfs partition, the changes won't persist. So, I used an rsync utility for this.

I want to know if some other option for this available:

Q1 : 
Can I mount the directory present in my secondary memory directly into RAM such that the directory contents also get copied into the mounted RAM partition while mounting itself.(It is not currently happening so, and I am supposed to use copy command for this).

Q2:
Can I mount an existing directory in secondary memory as ext file system (any other than ramfs and tmpfs) into RAM, if possible in case that would fetch files from RAM for reading and writing by my program but changes to files would persist in the directory that is mounted into RAM....

Thank you

Comment: Your basic requirement is not quite clear. Linux OS buffers files read/written intelligently in available RAM; so when there is enough RAM, there should be no performance advantage to have them in RAM a second time...

Comment: @ridgy  RAM is less in my machine (1GB). free -m shows free memory of upto 150 MB while I am running nothing.  My requirement is that I want to check options in reducing execution time of each cycle (while loop ) of a to be ported to real time application. So, am working around various ways of reducing application latency which is reading data files throughout its execution time. So, instead of using virtual memory as well as remove the delay occuring due to page fault at least the instance fopen() is called, if I copy all files to RAM ahead using ramfs and not tmpfs. So, same for output files

Comment: Some hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282276/write-through-ram-disk-or-massive-caching-of-file-system). Maybe [vmtouch](https://serverfault.com/questions/43383/caching-preloading-files-on-linux-into-ram) is still available (the page cited is a bit outdated).